# use column values as urls for web data sources

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a list query in Power BI with a bunch of urls, each url in the list opens a json file.
¿How can I loop through the list and add each json as a new web data source?
The manual process works fine when I copy each url and paste it in the [web source dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIp5k.png) but I want to automate this process, given that the elements in the list query are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of url's have a continues number which can be used as a parameter, you can use the List.Generate method and generate a list as in the below code:

```
= List.Generate(  
   ()  => [Offset = 0, Pokemon = "a" ],
   each [Offset] <= 200  , 
   each [ Offset = [Offset] + 100,
          Pokemon = [Pokemon] ] )
```

Please refer the below link for more info:
[How to use List.Generate to make API Calls in Power Query M](https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/)

From the info on the above link I created the Power BI Dashboard for Pokémon making dynamic rest API calls:
[Pokemon API Call Report](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkhIP0URJ6YKgSomPV_gufU28bJ7?e=PilSmF)

Comment: Thanks Vibhor, they actually are not made of numbers, just random hex id's. I found a solution which I posted as answer here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know Lucas.